# Give Span ID (ONE BY ONE) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have many span lists like

```
<span id="current"> hello </span>
<span> is </span>
<span> anyone </span>
<span> here</span>
```

I am performing an action using JavaScript

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
};
```

and I want that my `span id="current"` vanish and next  element i.e `<span> is </span>` gets an `id="current"`.

Comment: Right. So what have you tried?

Comment: that's what classes are for

Comment: no i can't use jquery

Comment: Why did you change the tags again? The problem has nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with DOM manipulation/traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Y5f/3/)

```
 var i = 1;
    document.onkeypress = function (evt) {

        var element = document.getElementById('current');
        alert(element.textContent);
        var sibling = element.parentNode.children;
        element.attributes.id.nodeValue = "newId" + i;
        sibling[i].id = "current";
        i++;
    };
```

Comment: first click on result window and then press any key. Try it

Comment: Why `element.attributes.id.nodeValue = "newId" + i;` and not `element.id = "newId" + i`?

Comment: both syntex works fine, you can choose any of them.

Comment: Of course, but why make it complicated when you can do it in a simple way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.onkeypress = function( e ) {
    var
        outboundEl = document.getElementById('current'),
        nextEl = outboundEl.nextElementSibling;

    // remove the #current element from the DOM but keep a reference to it
    outboundEl = outboundEl.parentNode.removeChild(outboundEl);

    // make sure we only grab a reference to a span
    if( nextEl && nextEl.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' ) {
        nextEl.id = outboundEl.id;
    }
};
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PSgQ2/

Comment: Just a thought, but once you've removed the element, will it still be available to the script in order to retrieve its `id` in the last line?

Comment: [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) removes the element from the DOM, but maintains a reference to it in memory.

Comment: Don't use `nextEl.setAttribute('id'` but `nextEl.id=`

Comment: @dystroy Any reason in particular?

Comment: @AndréDion From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.setAttribute) : *"Using setAttribute() to modify certain attributes, most notably value in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the properties. For example, use elt.value instead of elt.setAttribute('value', val)."*. The best reason is that it's simpler and a direct optimizable access to the property.

Comment: next element doesn't gets an id

Comment: If the HTML is like the OP posted it, then the next sibling of the `span` element is a text node, not the next `span` node. You have to traverse until you find the next element (`span`) node.

Comment: i can't still able to get the next span element an id

Comment: I've updated my solution based on feedback in the comments and have included a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PSgQ2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function idProgress (e) {
    var self = this,
        id = self.id,
        next = self.nextElementSibling;
    if (next === null) {
        // this assumes you don't want to remove the last element
        return false;
    }
    else {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
        next.id = id;
        next.addEventListener(e.type, idProgress);
    }
}

var span = document.getElementById('current');
span.addEventListener('click', idProgress);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R4SMM/).

To remove all the `span` elements click-by-click (including the last):

```
function idProgress (e) {
    var self = this,
        id = self.id,
        next = self.nextElementSibling;
    self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
    if (next !== null) {
        next.id = id;
        next.addEventListener(e.type, idProgress);
    }
}

var span = document.getElementById('current');
span.addEventListener('click', idProgress);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R4SMM/4/).

To use `keypress` rather than `click` (which I overlooked on first reading the question):

```
function idProgress (e) {
    var self = this.getElementById('current'),
        id = self.id,
        next = self.nextElementSibling,
        key = e.which;

    if (key !== 110 || next === null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
        next.id = id;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', idProgress);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R4SMM/2/).

Or:

```
function idProgress(e) {
    var self = this.getElementById('current'),
        id = self.id,
        next = self.nextElementSibling,
        key = e.which;
    if (key == 110) {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
        if (next !== null) {
            next.id = id;
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', idProgress);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R4SMM/3/).

References:

- [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener).
- [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.which).
- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementTraversal.nextElementSibling).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JQuery for this. Assign a class to all related  tags like 'class="deactiveSpan"' and assign one span element as class="activeSpan". Now you can get both types elements and handle it easily using jQuery.

Comment: i would use if i had done my previous work in jquery

Comment: You can learn basics of jQuery in few hours that'd be very useful for future. Here is a link for learning jquery:
http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/what-is-jquery/